# How to put table in full page when Document format is double column

Tags: templates, layout, latex, multirow, longtable

I have a Latex document with the elsarticle document class (Elsevier Journal) which is in double column. I'm trying to fit a long table into a single column, but it doesn't work, the table is messy and doesn't take up the full width. I've tried adding a * to the longtable command, but that doesn't work either.

UPDATE: I also tried the command `\onecolumn` after `begin{longtable}` and the command `\doublecolumn` at the end, but it didn't work, the full paper becomes one column, which I don't want.

An extract of my table with sample data (but with far fewer rows) is below :

```
\documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{%
\begingroup
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{longtable} [c]{p{1cm}p{1.8cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{2.1cm}p{1.3cm}p{2cm}}
\caption{High Level Overview of Existing Frameworks}
\label{tab:general-description-v1}\\
\hline
%\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
\textbf{Name} &
\textbf{Authors} &
\textbf{Year} &
\textbf{Column A} &
 \textbf{Column B} & 
\textbf{Column C} &
  \textbf{Column D} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
%\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
\textbf{Name} &
\textbf{Authors} &
\textbf{Year} &
 \textbf{Column A} &
 \textbf{Column B} &
 \textbf{Column C} &
\textbf{Column D} \\ \hline
\endhead
%

AA\textsuperscript{*}&
citation 1 &
2019 - 2020 &
data 1 &
data 2 &
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 3\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 4\end{tabular} \\ \hline

  
\multirow{2}{*}{BB\textsuperscript{*} }
&citation 2 &
  2010 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 1 \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 2\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 3\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 4\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-7}

&citation 3 &
  2013 &
  data 1 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 2\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 3\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 4\end{tabular} \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\endgroup
}%
\raggedbottom

\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to oncolumn mode before you start the `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\afterpage{%
\begingroup
\onecolumn
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{longtable} [c]{p{1cm}p{1.8cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{2.1cm}p{1.3cm}p{2cm}}
\caption{High Level Overview of Existing Frameworks}
\label{tab:general-description-v1}\\
\hline
%\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
\textbf{Name} &
\textbf{Authors} &
\textbf{Year} &
\textbf{Column A} &
 \textbf{Column B} & 
\textbf{Column C} &
  \textbf{Column D} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
%\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
\textbf{Name} &
\textbf{Authors} &
\textbf{Year} &
 \textbf{Column A} &
 \textbf{Column B} &
 \textbf{Column C} &
\textbf{Column D} \\ \hline
\endhead
%

AA\textsuperscript{*}&
citation 1 &
2019 - 2020 &
data 1 &
data 2 &
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 3\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 4\end{tabular} \\ \hline

  
\multirow{2}{*}{BB\textsuperscript{*} }
&citation 2 &
  2010 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 1 \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 2\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 3\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 4\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-7}

&citation 3 &
  2013 &
  data 1 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 2\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 3\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}data 4\end{tabular} \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\twocolumn
\endgroup
}%
\raggedbottom

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your current approach does effectively make the tables full-width while keeping a double-column layout for the text. However, a significant problem arises with this solution. Due to the tables' length, my document encounters excessive empty space either below or sometimes before the tables. This can lead to one of the double-columns being entirely blank until the table starts on the next page. As a result, the text frequently continues on the following pages.

Do you have any suggestions for addressing and resolving this issue?